# Too many buckets, aggregation fails on histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a query to elastic that contains total 8 nested aggregations, all aggregations are `term` aggregations except one which is a `histogram` aggregation. If I remove that histogram aggregation, the query runs perfectly. But with histogram aggregation it is throwing this particular error:

> This aggregation creates too many buckets (10001) and will throw an
>   error in future versions. You should update the [search.max_buckets]
>   cluster setting or use the [composite] aggregation to paginate all
>   buckets in multiple requests.

Now I tried increasing the `max_buckets` size but the size is reaching above 100000 and also that number is not certain so that option is out. Then I tried creating a `composite` aggregation as suggested in the error but that is also giving the same error with the histogram added.

So my question is am I writing the queries in some wrong fashion or elastic is not feasible enough to create that much of buckets?

**Kibana query:** (with only 3 levels of nesting, original problem have 8)

```
GET /project/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                "range": {
                    "date" : {
                        "gte": 20180101,
                        "lte": 20180630
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "agg1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "agg1"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "agg2": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "agg2"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "agg3": {
                            "histogram": {
                                "field": "agg3",
                                "interval": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this to change your cluster setting (search.max_buckets) larger.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_buckets": 50000
  }
}
```

Comment: The question explicitly rules out changing the `max_buckets` value.

Comment: ```max_buckets``` It depends on how many keys you have in your data or the size you want.

Comment: From the question text: "I tried increasing the `max_buckets` size but **the size is reaching above 100000** and also **that number is not certain** so **that option is out**".

Comment: When you have a million users it can be a million, and when you need more it can be bigger by default, and the storage is always finite, so theoretically this value is finite

Comment: Yes I get it, you can increase this number by a lot, but the performances hit will be _big_, OP is right to be concerned about increasing it too much. Also OP said that the number is not certain, so **changing that number is not an option**. It's better to optimize (rewrite) the query than to throw huge amounts of resources at it. Elastic was not made for computing all the 9-permutations of a field.