# AWS Elastic Search service too_many_buckets_exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Cloud: AWS
ES Version: 7.4

Error message while searching:

```
{"error":{"message":"[too_many_buckets_exception] Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [110000] but was [110001]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting., with { max_buckets=110000 }"}}
```

The question is where/how can I set this property from AWS console OR AWS cli.

The AWS console

Regards
Amit Meena

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57424700/4604579

Comment: Thanks for quick response, let me check :)

Comment: Hi @Val, I tried that but for me the the AWS ES is reposnding with : {
    "Message": "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."
}

Comment: Are you using the [flat settings form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_api_notes)?

Comment: Not aware about that, We are using managed elastic search service provided by AWS and from the documentation it seems that they are not allowing to tweak this property : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_4

Comment: Indeed, with AWS managed ES, you're out of luck

Comment: :) yeah seems like that, I will taise a defect/suppot ticket.

Comment: Or switch to Elastic Cloud :-)